# SpringBoot with OAuth2 authentication + Form authentication together issue

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm building a system using Spring Boot and I would like to authenticate a user in two ways:

- Form authentication
- Oauth2 authentication

1) I would like that users that login through Oauth2 are able to call /api/** urls but cannot access /admin/** section

2) I would like that users that login through Form are able to access /admin/** section but cannot access /api/**

In the first case the authentication will happen for example through a CURL call while on the second case through a web form.

Now configuring spring-boot I could authenticate in both ways but never they were working together. When I configure the formLogin I cannot authenticate with the Oauth2 and viceversa.

below the **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    public static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }

}
```

and the **OAuth2Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "bancadati";

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                    .disable()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();


        }
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";

        private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.jdbc(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
        }

    }}
```

I also tried to do some changes for instance I changed .authenticated() into .fullyAuthenticated() in the **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** but nothing changed. I tried also to follow this example https://github.com/rynkowsw/web-and-oauth2-security with no luck!

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

may be can help someone else below the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
  }
}
```

The authorization server configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationConfiguration {
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
    }
 }
}
```